# FAIL - Deployed application at context path /website but context failed to start?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have been trying to deploy a web.xml file using TOMCAT WEB APPLICATION MANAGER,

Context Path (required): /website
 
XML Configuration file URL: C:\DOCUME~1\Graeme\workspace\website\website.xml
WAR or Directory URL:

When I Deploy I get as a message: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /website but context failed to start

Therefore the question is why am I not able to deploy my application successfully